# how can i localise jquery datepicker in RAD portal server based on the locale as french or english

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, localization, rad, websphere-portal

in any jsp i have

```
<f:view locale="javaclass.locale">
```

The usercontext.java stores the locale of the logged-in user. I can access the locale as

```
usercontext.getlocale();
```

I need the datepicker to automatically appear in french or english based on the logged-in user.

Comment: tried this http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/localization.html

Comment: This website is known to all and everyone has gone through it.I dont need a dropdown. i need it to happen automatically based on the logged-in user's locale. I mentioned this in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Using a similar approach to the localization demo at http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#localization you use a little script that sets the default locale on the datepicker before you create it via jQuery.

```
<script type="javascript">
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["${usercontext.locale}"]);
</script>
```

Or could you set the locale of the datepicker as you create it.

```
<script type="javascript">
    $("#datepicker").datepicker($.datepicker.regional["${usercontext.locale"]);
</script>
```